C# Unity: How do I make Grappling Hook swing from building to building?
I need to make a 'Spiderman' game using Raycast to make my character move with a grappling hook/spiderweb swinging motion, and I need to use a linerenderer to show the spiderweb. With my code below, the linerenderer is shown and hangs on to a building when I press control, but my player still can't swing. How do I make my player swing from building to building using the linerenderer?
P.S. in my Unity engine, I have a Player game object with Rigidbody, capsule collider, linerenderer, and GrapplingHook & PlayerMovement scripts components. My building are cube prefabs.
Grappling Hook code, attached to Player game object:
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingHook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float maxDistance = 100f;
    private Vector3 grapplePoint;
    private SpringJoint joint;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    
     void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            StartGrapple();
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1")) {
            StopGrapple();
        }
    }

    void StartGrapple()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, playerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance))
        {
            grapplePoint = hit.point;
            joint = gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;

            float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, grapplePoint);

            // The distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point
            joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
            joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;

            joint.spring = 4.5f;
            joint.damper = 7f;
            joint.massScale = 4.5f;

            lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
        }
    }

    void StopGrapple()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        Destroy(joint);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (lineRenderer.positionCount > 0)
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, grapplePoint);
        }
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (joint != null)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                rb.AddForce(-transform.right * 10f); // Add leftward force
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                rb.AddForce(transform.right * 10f); // Add rightward force
            }
        }
    }
}

Player movement code, also attached to Player game object:
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime*5;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            transform.position += -transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            transform.position += -transform.right * Time.deltaTime;
        
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
            transform.position += transform.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 0.25f);
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, 0.25f);
        }
        
        
    }
    
}


"Logically", you're "wheeling" a line on one end and "spiderman" is hanging on the sweeping end. Spiderman's position should be tied to the line's (moving) end point. (An extrapolation based on line origin, angle and radius (length of line))
